# How to refresh cognito access token in javascript application (AngullarJS) if application client does not generate client secret

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, access-token

How to refresh cognito access token in javascript application (AngullarJS) if application client does not generate client secret?

I tried to use the following query but it returns:{"error":"invalid_client"}

```
let dt = {
    grant_type: "refresh_token", 
    client_id: "xxxxxxxxx", 
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    refresh_token: "my_refresh_token"
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://example.com/oauth2/token",
    data: dt,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("success!!!");
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("error!!!");
}});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks mostly OK though a redirect_uri parameter should not be sent on this request. Try removing that. Also see if adding a scope parameter makes a difference (though that should be optional). Of course take care to verify the client_id carefully.

Here is a working POST from a public client (demo app) of mine. I can confirm that this grant works fine in Cognito for public clients.

[image: refresh]